# MWPhotoBrowser with button and error handeling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm trying to make a app that uses a photobrowser
Decided to go with the MWPhotoBrowser.

This is the code, but i cant seem to make it work:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MWPhotoBrowserDelegate> {
    NSArray *_photos;
    UISegmentedControl *_segmentedControl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *photos;
- (IBAction)billede:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize photos = _photos;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_segmentedControl] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (IBAction)billede:(id)sender {

    //show your photo whit url
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MWPhoto *photo;
    {
    photo = [MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo2l" ofType:@"jpg"]];
    photo.caption = @"The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames, in London, England.";
    [photos addObject:photo];
    }

    self.photos = photos;

    // Create browser
    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    browser.displayActionButton = YES;

    //browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    //[browser setInitialPageIndex:2];

    // Show
    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        // Push
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
    } else {
        // Modal
        UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browser];
        nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
        [nc release];
    }



}


#pragma mark - MWPhotoBrowserDelegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {

    return _photos.count;

}



- (MWPhoto *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:   (NSUInteger)index {

    if (index < _photos.count)

        return [_photos objectAtIndex:index];

    return nil;

}

@end
```

I've tried both with ARC and wothout ARC

Without ARC i get 3 errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhoto"**, referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>     **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhotoBrowser"**, referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

With ARC i get 2 errors

Problem 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuxrJ.png

Problem 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsWXQ.png

I've not done it here, but i would like it alle to be wrapped in a button so i can click that and show a image inside the MWPhotoBrowser

**Edit**

I have upgraded my code, removed ARC from my files and i have now set the target right.
It will compile now, but everytime i triy to click the button: "billede" i get:

```
    2012-11-26 23:32:10.955 MWPhotoBrowserTest[10405:c07] -[ViewController galleri:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x947fb20
2012-11-26 23:32:10.957 MWPhotoBrowserTest[10405:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController galleri:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x947fb20'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d34012 0x14e9e7e 0x1dbf4bd 0x1d23bbc 0x1d2394e 0x14fd705 0x434920 0x4348b8 0x4f5671 0x4f5bcf 0x4f4d38 0x46433f 0x464552 0x4423aa 0x433cf8 0x1f6ddf9 0x1f6dad0 0x1ca9bf5 0x1ca9962 0x1cdabb6 0x1cd9f44 0x1cd9e1b 0x1f6c7e3 0x1f6c668 0x43165c 0x1e2d 0x1d55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: Which way are you adding this library to your project? As a library or including the source?

Comment: I'm including the source

Comment: Did you remember to add MWPhoto.m and MWPhotoBrowser.m? Is the Target Membership set properly for both files?

Comment: Where do you mean i have to add MWPhoto.m and MWPhotoBrowser.m?


I got it to open now! It was in the test file that wasn't using ARC (I thought it was optimized to use ARC?) But when i clicked the button i get error and app freezes..

Comment: fixed my code and target membership, now i only need to get the button to show my image when i click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually resolved this. 
I've struggled for 4 days and finally got it.
I read through https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser#method-1-static-library and understood it, finally but i had a problem with User header Search Path.
I finally got it, importet MWPhotoBrowser folder into my MWPhotoBrowser"project" folder and then sat User Header Search Path to ".." instead of "../**" since "../**" gave me "../**../**"

Hope this helps anyone who might stand in the same problem as me!

Btw, thanks for the help guys! :-)

Comment: Did you set it as recursive search? I find myself struggling with this as well, but it only happens when I try to archive my project...

Answer (score 1):

Attachment 1:
You can't add objects to NSArray, use NSMutableArray instead.

Attachment 2:
UIView has no methods "reloadData", but for exmple UITableView does.

Comment: Paul:
1 I'll try it as soon as i get to my computer!
2. I get an error when trying UITableView